# Connection refused - not consistent

Tags: http, connection

I have an application that is used to make hotel bookings. The application takes an XML message, transforms the XML into another XML message and sends this new XML to another application. I am able to book hotels successfully.

When I try to amend this booking (different XML request, same application, same URL) I get a 'Connection refused' error.

I would have thought that there'd be consistency (all work or none) but there's not.

Anyone any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Connection refused" means that no application is accepting connections on the port and host that you try to connect to. It can be caused by

- The application is actually running on a different host or a different port
- The application crashed and hasn't been restarted
- The application is buggy: it closes the listening server socket from time to time, so that it is not listening for connection attempts all the time
- Firewall is configured to respond to new connections with a "connection refused" even if the application was able to accept a connection

Comment: Wouldn't the above make sense but for the fact that hotel bookings work but amendments do not.. There is no consistency.

Comment: Most likely you are not sending the requests to the same place. Double check everything, and use tcpdump or wireshark or some other network monitoring tool to see where the application tries to connect.

Comment: To send messages to my application, I have written a little test tool to post the requests. The application then transforms the message and sends it to another app. The connect refused it as this second step. I wouldn't be able to use Wireshark for that part, considering both the primary and secondary apps are on different machines to my test tool?

Comment: If the problem is between the primary and secondary apps, it's the traffic between those two that you have to debug.

Comment: Agreed. Is that possible considering they're both deployed on remote servers?

Comment: You can run `tcpdump` or `wireshark` on a remote server.

Comment: According to the WireShark docs, to monitor a remote interface, you have to install WinPcap on the remote system. I do not have access to this remote server. Doomed to failure?

Comment: In that case you should ask for help from the sysadmin or the network admin. You need access to the failing system to debug it.